# Line segment equation in polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

I have a line segment given by two points $A$ and $B$. $$A+u(B-A), u\in[0,1]$$

when doing calculations with this segment, it would be advantageous to have it written in polar coordinates around some point $S$. More specifically, in the form $$r=f(\phi)$$

I could brute force this expression but the result starts getting ugly, fast. Is there some insight I can use that would give me a simpler definition of $f$ using $A$, $B$ and $S$?

Comment: What is the meaning of point $S$? Since that is not clear, I used the origin in my answer.

Comment: S is supposed to be the relative origin of the polar coordinates.

Comment: Is $S$ given, or can the answerer choose $S$? And are $r$ and $\phi$ then relative to $S$?

Comment: S is given, and yes, $r$ and $\phi$ are relative to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that points $A$ and $B$ are $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in Cartesian coordinates and $(r_1,\theta_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2)$ in polar coordinates.

Then the direction angle of the line segment is given by

$$\theta_0=\begin{cases}
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}\right),  & x_1\ne x_2 \\
\frac{\pi}2, & x_1=x_2
\end{cases}
$$
And the signed distance from the origin to the line containing points $A$ and $B$ is

$$d_0=r_1\sin(\theta_1-\theta_0)=r_2\sin(\theta_2-\theta_0)$$

(Use either formula for $d_0$: you get the same result.) If $d_0\ne 0$ then the line containing points $A$ and $B$ does not pass through the origin, and the polar equation of that line is

> $$r=\frac{d_0}{\sin(\theta-\theta_0)}$$

and to get only the segment on the line just require that $\theta$ is between $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

If $d_0=0$ then the line containing points $A$ and $B$ does pass through the origin, and thus $r$ is not a function of $\theta$ and another kind of polar equation will be required to specify the line, such as $\theta=\theta_1$ with $r$ limited to be between $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Note that the "distance" $d_0$ may be negative. If that is not desired, replace $d_0$ with $-d_0$ and $\theta_0$ with $\theta_0+\pi$ or $\theta_0-\pi$.

This diagram explains much of those formulas.

[image]

Comment: That extremely neat. I am having trouble seeing how the formula for r is derived.

Comment: @LukaHorvat: From the diagram you can see that $d_0=r_1\sin(\theta_1-\theta_0)$ (up to $\pm$). But that same will hold for any other point on the line: $d_0=r\sin(\theta-\theta_0)$, so $r=\frac{d_0}{\sin(\theta-\theta_0)}$. I left out the general point in my diagram, thinking it would just clutter the diagram. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for answering!

Comment: Do you know any way of getting $\theta_0$ (angle or slope) without converting to Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @FernandoPelliccioni: I can see several ways, but probably the simplest is to substitute $x_1=r_1\cos\theta_1$ etc. into my formula for $\theta_0$, giving $$\theta_0=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{r_2\sin\theta_2-r_1\sin\theta_1}{r_2\cos\theta_2-r_1\cos\theta_1}\right)$$ for the denominator non-zero, or $\pi/2$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @RoryDaulton.
But here you are actually transforming to cartesian

Comment: @FernandoPelliccioni: The Cartesian coordinates are not seen in that formula, so who cares if I used them to get the formula? After all, the very definition of $\theta_0$ refers to the Cartesian plane. Do you really need another formula?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, I need another formula because I am trying to solve something like:

I have 3 points: $A$, $B$ and $C$, that are $(r_1,n \cdot \theta_1)$, $(r_2,n \cdot \theta_2)$ and $(r_3,n \cdot \theta_3)$ in Polar coordinates, with $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

I have to compare for equality the slope of the line segments $AB$ and $BC$ (for example). So:

Comment: @RoryDaulton (continuation)


$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{r_2 \cdot sin(n \cdot \theta_2)-r_1 \cdot sin(n \cdot \theta_1)}{r_2 \cdot cos(n \cdot \theta_2)-r_1 \cdot cos(n \cdot \theta_1)}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{r_3 \cdot sin(n \cdot \theta_3)-r_2 \cdot sin(n \cdot \theta_2)}{r_3 \cdot cos(n \cdot \theta_3)-r_2 \cdot cos(n \cdot \theta_2)}\right)$$


Then I need to get $n$.  
But... it is very difficult to solve the equation.  

$n$ means the $\mathbb{Z}$ value for the points $A$, $B$ and $C$ be collinear.

Comment: $$\tan^{-1}\left(\right)$$ could be eliminated.