# Integration over portion of circle

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, circles, polar-coordinates

I need to find the integral region $\mathcal R$ which covers area CPRQ portion of the circle radius $t$.

[image]
The integration looks as
$$I=\int\int_{\mathcal R}f(r,\theta)dr d\theta$$

Can someone help me to write these polar coordinate integration limits for $r$ and $\theta$?

If necessary, he angle $RCQ$ is $\beta$ where $Tan\, \beta=\frac{d}{h}$.

The angle $ROQ$ is $\alpha$ where 
$\cos\,\alpha = \frac{h \left(\sqrt{d^2+h^2} \sqrt{t^2-\frac{d^2 h^2}{d^2+h^2}}+d^2\right)}{t \left(d^2+h^2\right)}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the equation for a line not through the origin in polar coordinates?

Comment: @David I am not much familiar but I have looked at some examples such as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430448/polar-coordinates-of-a-line-not-passing-through-the-origin I am not sure how it can be applied in this case.

Comment: Sadly, that question-asker was confused; the question did not actually involve polar coordinates. Try https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382437/line-segment-equation-in-polar-coordinates instead.

Comment: I really didnt understand how this line equation helps my problem. Can you please elaborate this more?

Comment: If your outer integral is over $\theta$ and your inner integral is over $r,$ you need to get the bounds of $r$ along each radial line as a  function of $\theta.$ The upper bound is easy, because the integration along every radial line ends on the circle. But the integration _starts_ on one of the lines $CQ$ or $BP,$ so you need to know how to compute the radius at which each radial line crosses one of those lines, as a function of the angle of the radial line. That function is just the function of the line in polar coordinates.